# Python - Save data from Process to use on Main - Websocket

Tags: python, websocket, process

Ok, what I'm trying to do is work with the information that a websocket gives me. But since it remains in a loop I decided to start said websocket in a process. The problem now is I don't know how to get the information of that process in loop from main.
I tried with a .txt but I suppose that errors are generated when one function tries to overwrite and the other tries to open it, because executing the entire code my process did not edit the content of the .txt or at least `capture()` doesn't take the changes

```
def on_message(ws,msg):
    with open("f.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(msg)
        f.close
def startWebSocket():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever()

def capture():
    s=True
    while s:
        with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "f.txt"), "r") as f:
            if f.readable():
                msg = json.loads(f.read())
                f.close
                s=False
    #work with msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=startWebSocket)
    p.start()
    p.join()

capture()
```

I hope it is understood. Working with .txt is what I was trying now, but if there are better solutions please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way I found is to create a sqlite database and use it on both sides

The thing to keep in mind is that two processes must be created for everything to work properly. In my case:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=startWebSocket)
    p2 = Process(target=capture)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```